# What's the wrong with the number of days?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DateFormatter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

 public class Calendar extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private JButton Next, Previous;
private JLabel CurrDate,Time;
private JLabel Days[];
private JButton [] dayButtons;
private JPanel P1,P2,P3,P4,P5;
private int year , month , day ,ch;
String S1;
GregorianCalendar GC=new GregorianCalendar();;
int DayOfWeek=GC.get(GC.DAY_OF_WEEK);

Color c = new Color(169,97,182);
Color c2 = new Color(241,233,241);
String[] months =  {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",    "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
Calendar()
{        
    super( "Calendar" );

    year = GC.get(GC.YEAR);
    month = GC.get(GC.MONTH);
    day = GC.get(GC.DATE);


    Previous = new JButton ("<<");
    Previous.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    Previous.addActionListener(this);
    Next = new JButton (">>");
    Next.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    Next.addActionListener(this);

    CurrDate = new JLabel ("                   "+ months[month]+"        "+year+"               ");
    CurrDate.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    CurrDate.setFont(new Font ("Serif",Font.ITALIC+Font.BOLD,15));
    CurrDate.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    Days = new JLabel[7];
    Days[0] = new JLabel ("Sun         ");
    Days[1] = new JLabel ("Mon         ");
    Days[2] = new JLabel ("Tue         ");
    Days[3] = new JLabel ("Wed         ");
    Days[4] = new JLabel ("Thu         ");
    Days[5] = new JLabel ("Fri            ");
    Days[6] = new JLabel ("Sat         ");
    for(JLabel l : Days)
    {
        l. setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        l.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    }
    Time = new JLabel ();
    Time.setText(GC.get(GC.HOUR)+":"+GC.get(GC.MINUTE)+":"+GC.get(GC.SECOND));
    Time.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    if( month ==0 || month ==2 || month == 4 || month ==6 || month==7 || month ==9 || month ==11)
    {
        ch = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ch = 2;
    }

    P1 = new JPanel();
    P2 = new JPanel();
    P3 = new JPanel();
    P4 = new JPanel();
    P5 = new JPanel();
    P5.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    P1.add(Previous); 
    P1.add(CurrDate);   
    DrawCalendar(DayOfWeek,year,month);
    P1.add(Next);
    P2.add(Days[0]);
    P2.add(Days[1]);
    P2.add(Days[2]);
    P2.add(Days[3]);
    P2.add(Days[4]);
    P2.add(Days[5]);
    P2.add(Days[6]);

    P4.add(Time);
    P1.setBackground(c);
    P2.setBackground(c);
    P4.setBackground(c);

    P5.add (P1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    P5.add (P2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add (P5,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add (P3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add (P4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

private void DrawCalendar(int DayOfWeek, int year, int month) {
    P3.setLayout( new GridLayout(7,7,3,3));
    dayButtons = new JButton [49];


    if(DayOfWeek == 1 && ch ==1)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 31; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i+1 +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 31; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 2 && ch ==1)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i = 1; i < 32; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 32; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 3 && ch ==1)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i =2; i < 33; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i-1 +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 33; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 4 && ch ==1)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i =3; i < 34; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i-2 +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 34; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 5 && ch ==1)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i =4; i < 35; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i-3 +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 35; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 6 && ch ==1)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i =5; i < 36; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i-4 +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 36; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 7 && ch ==1)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i =6; i < 37; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i-5 +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 37; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 1 && ch ==2)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( i+1+"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 30; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 

    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 2 && ch ==2)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i =1; i < 31; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 31; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 3 && ch ==2)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i =2; i < 32; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i-1 +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 32; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 4 && ch ==2)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i =3; i < 33; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i-2 +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 33; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 5 && ch ==2)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i =4; i < 35; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i-3 +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 35; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 6 && ch ==2)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i =5; i < 36; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i-4 +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 36; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    if(DayOfWeek == 7 && ch ==2)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
        for ( int i =6; i < 37; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton(  i-5 +"" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(c2);
         } 
        for ( int i = 37; i < 49; i++ )
         { dayButtons[ i ] = new JButton( "" ); 
         P3.add( dayButtons[ i ] );
         dayButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
         dayButtons[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         } 
    }
    for( int i = DayOfWeek-1; i<49 ; i++)
    {
        if( i- DayOfWeek+2 == GC.get(GC.DATE))
        {
            dayButtons[i].setBackground(c);
        }
    }


}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


    if(arg0.getSource()== Previous)
    {   clear();


        if(month !=0)
        {
            month --;

            if( month ==0 || month ==2 || month == 4 || month ==6 || month==7 || month ==9 || month ==11)
            {
                ch=1;
            }
            else
            {
                ch=2;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            year--;
            month=11;
            ch=1;
        }
        CurrDate.setText ("                   "+ months[month]+"        "+year+"               ");
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
        int d=cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        DayOfWeek=d;
        DrawCalendar(d,year,month);

        P4.add(Time);
        P1.setBackground(c);
        P2.setBackground(c);
        P4.setBackground(c);
    }
    if(arg0.getSource()== Next)
    {
        clear();

        if(month !=11)
        {
            month ++;
            if( month ==0 || month ==2 || month == 4 || month ==6 || month==7 || month ==9 || month ==11)
            {
                ch=1;
            }
            else
            {
                ch=2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            year++;
            month=0;
            ch=1;

        }
        CurrDate.setText ("                   "+ months[month]+"        "+year+"               ");
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
        int d=cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        DayOfWeek=d;
        DrawCalendar(d,year,month);
        P4.add(Time);
        P1.setBackground(c);
        P2.setBackground(c);
        P4.setBackground(c);

    }   
    for( int i=DayOfWeek-1; i<30+DayOfWeek; i++)
    {
        if(arg0.getSource()==dayButtons[i])
        {
            S1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Insert your Note");

        }
    }


}

private void clear() {
    for(int i =0; i<6;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            P3.removeAll();
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String [] args){
    Calendar C = new Calendar();
    C.setSize(400,315);

    C.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    C.setVisible(true);
    C.setResizable(false);
    }


}
```

hello all,,, :)

the problem with this Calendar the number of days in each month !
the code I wrote ,, doesn't work as what it should do !
I don't know where is the problem 
If any one can help,, thnx anyway!

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could define the problem a little more clearly... May does have 31 days.

Comment: Java Day of Week http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/DayOfWeek.html

Comment: Any chance you can simplify this code at all to make it easier to find the problem?

Comment: 7th day is printed in purple, that's the thing he has problem.

Comment: if u press the next button or the previous one,, it doesn't give you the number of days that you should have

some times its always 31 ... and the other not like wt it should be.

even I wrote the code which relates to every case :(

Comment: You've given *500 lines* of code including a GUI, to demonstrate a problem which I suspect you could *far* more easily demonstrate in a 10 line console app. Change it into a short console app so we don't have to wade through hundreds of lines of irrelevant code, and I'll take a look...

Comment: I don't know where is the problem ! so I don't know which code should I write for you programmers !

Comment: I would like to point out that the 7th is a Monday, not a Sunday.

Comment: yeah I know , its another problem with the day of week , bt I can fix it easily the problem now is with the number of days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce your code much, if you parametrize repeated code invocation:

```
private void tripleDraw (int n1, int n2, int d) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    { 
        dayButtons [i] = new JButton (""); 
        P3.add (dayButtons [i]);
        dayButtons [i].setBackground (Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    } 
    for (int i = n1; i < n2; i++)
    {
        dayButtons [i] = new JButton (i+d + ""); 
        P3.add (dayButtons [i]);
        dayButtons [i].setBackground (c2);
    } 
    for (int i = n2; i < 49; i++)
    { 
        dayButtons [i] = new JButton (""); 
        P3.add (dayButtons [i]);
        dayButtons [i].setBackground (Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    } 
}

private void DrawCalendar (int DayOfWeek, int year, int month) 
{
    P3.setLayout (new GridLayout (7, 7, 3, 3));
    dayButtons = new JButton [49];

    if (DayOfWeek == 1 && ch == 1)  tripleDraw (0, 31, 1);
    if (DayOfWeek == 2 && ch == 1)  tripleDraw (1, 32, 0);
    if (DayOfWeek == 3 && ch == 1)  tripleDraw (2, 33, -1);
    if (DayOfWeek == 4 && ch == 1)  tripleDraw (3, 34, -2);
    if (DayOfWeek == 5 && ch == 1)  tripleDraw (4, 35, -3);
    if (DayOfWeek == 6 && ch == 1)  tripleDraw (5, 36, -4);
    if (DayOfWeek == 7 && ch == 1)  tripleDraw (6, 37, -5);  

    if (DayOfWeek == 1 && ch == 2)  tripleDraw (0, 30, 1);
    if (DayOfWeek == 2 && ch == 2)  tripleDraw (1, 31, 0);
    if (DayOfWeek == 3 && ch == 2)  tripleDraw (2, 32, -1);
    if (DayOfWeek == 4 && ch == 2)  tripleDraw (3, 33, -2);
    if (DayOfWeek == 5 && ch == 2)  tripleDraw (4, 35, -3);
    if (DayOfWeek == 6 && ch == 2)  tripleDraw (5, 36, -4);
    if (DayOfWeek == 7 && ch == 2)  tripleDraw (6, 37, -5);
```

Then you see in the second block (ch==2), that there is a jump from 33 to 35 - is it intentional?

The next step would be, to replace the first block with:

```
 if (ch == 1)  tripleDraw (DayOfWeek - 1, DayOfWeek + 31, 2-DayOfWeek);
```

and so on.

Comment: Then you see in the second block (ch==2), that there is a jump from 33 to 35 - is it intentional?


No,, It's NOT :D
thnx alot

Answer (score 2):

The reason the number of days is always 31 is because you're not recalculating "ch" when the button is clicked.

The reason you couldn't figure this out, is because your implementation uses about 5-10 times as much code as should really be required, and because it's a mess.
Also because you probably didn't use a debugger to debug this.

Use default rules from Checkstyle, FindBugs, PMD etc to tell you some of the things that are wrong with your code.

Comment: Actually ,, I recalculate it in each click !





if(month !=0)
   {
    month --;
    
    if( month ==0 || month ==2 || month == 4 || month ==6 || month==7 || month ==9 || month ==11)
    {
     ch=1;
    }
    else
    {
     ch=2;
    }
   
   }
   else
   {
    year--;
    month=11;
       ch=1;
   }

Comment: No, you don't. The actionPerformed method is called on each click and you are not recalculating 'ch' each time there.